# Django Channels CustomAuthentication close_old_connections SynchronousOnlyOperation exception

Tags: python, django, authentication, websocket, channel

I tried to implement the CustomAuthentication from the [Django Channels documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html#custom-authentication) but i'm getting a SynchronousOnlyOperation exception every time i try to establish a websocket connection. What am i missing?

I tried to use `database_sync_to_async` from `channels.db` but then i'm stuck with a coroutine object as a return value even if i'm using `await`. Maybe someone has an idea what i'm doing wrong?

**Package Versions:**

- Python 3.6.9
- Django 3.0.2
- ASGI/Channels 2.4.0
- Daphne 2.4.1
- asgiref 3.2.3
- channels-redis 2.4.1

**Database:**

- sqlite3

**Execution:**

`python3 manage.py runserver`

**Files:**

*settings.py*

```py
[...]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)]
        },
    },
}

[...]
```

*routing.py* (application)

```py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import backend.api.routing as route
from backend.api.auth import TicketAuthMiddleware

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': TicketAuthMiddleware(
        URLRouter(
            route.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

*routing.py* (url)

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from backend.api.consumers import OwnConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
        re_path(r'<url>', OwnConsumer)
        ]
```

*consumers.py*

```py
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json

class OwnConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("disconnected", close_code)
```

*auth.py*

```py
from django.db import close_old_connections

class TicketAuthMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __call__(self, scope):
       close_old_connections() # <--- raising SynchronousOnlyOperation exception
       return self.inner(dict(scope))
```

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 at the moment

Answer (score 0):

It's a documented issue at the moment, evidently with Django 3:
https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1399 (the solution is inside).